# Adding values to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I what to get a value returned from a object method and put it into an array. The codes is as follows:

```
$additionalTestConfirmation = array();

$additionalTests = $this->getAdditionalTestsSelected();


foreach($additionalTests as $availableTest)
{
  $additionalTestConfirmation = $availableTest->getName();

}

$appointment = $this->getAppointment();

$tokens = array(
  '%DATE%' => $this->getAppointment()->getDate(),
  '%LOCATION%' => $this->getAppointment()->getLocation(),
  '%TIME%' => $this->getTime(),
  '%ROOM%' => $this->getRoom(),
  '%NAME%' => ($this->getUser() ? $this->getUser()->getFullName() : null),
  '%TZ%'   => $this->getAppointment()->getShowTimeZone() ? $this->getAppointment()->getTimeZone() : '',
  '%AdditionalTestsSelected%' => $additionalTestConfirmation,
);
```

For the codes above, I got a system error message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /Users/alexhu/NetBeansProjects/menagerie/svn/trunk/apps/frontend/modules/legacy/legacy_lib/lib/classes/AppointmentTime.php on line 379. 
How do I avoid this and get the $availableTest->getName() returned value I want. thanks

Comment: What is line 379? What has your question headline to do with your question actually?

Comment: You've been asking questions about every single step of whatever it is you're doing for 2 days now. May I suggest you learn PHP and then come back when you have well defined problems?

Comment: Text editors (e.g. vim, emacs) can be made to display line numbers when editing, which is very useful if you want to figure out which is line number 379, for example (especially if you want to post the relevant piece of code in an SO question). Spend some time building expertise with your text editor, and you will make your life as a programmer much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign elements to an array, you must either specify an index, or use empty square brackets (`[]`) to add an item:

```
foreach($additionalTests as $availableTest) {
  $additionalTestConfirmation[] = $availableTest->getName();
  // or array_push($additionalTestConfirmation, $availableTest->getName()); 
  // see: http://us3.php.net/array_push
}
```

See the docs for more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

**EDIT**

Also, on this line:

```
'%AdditionalTestsSelected%' => $additionalTestConfirmation,
```

... you are passing an array into this index. If the code afterword expects this to be a string, that could cause the errors. **This is not causing the error* - it is perfectly acceptable to put an array in another array. As I mentioned, though, it really depends on what the code that uses the `$tokens` array will do and expect. If it expects a plain string for the `AdditionalTestsSelected` index, you might need to do this:

```
'%AdditionalTestsSelected%' => implode(',', $additionalTestConfirmation)
```

... to make the value a comma-delimited list.

Also note, at the end of that line you have an extra comma.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I still got the error. I think it is about '%AdditionalTestsSelected%' => $additionalTestConfirmation

Comment: Through this answer, or otherwise? If not through this answer, you ought to post your solution as an answer in case someone else has the same problem in the future!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($additionalTests as $availableTest)
{
  $additionalTestConfirmation[] = $availableTest->getName();

}
```

after your comment I propose you this:

```
$appointment = $this->getAppointment();

$token = array(
  '%DATE%' => $appointment->getDate(),
  '%LOCATION%' => $appointment->getLocation(),
  '%TIME%' => $this->getTime(),
  '%ROOM%' => $this->getRoom(),
  '%NAME%' => ($this->getUser() ? $this->getUser()->getFullName() : null),
  '%TZ%'   => $appointment->getShowTimeZone() ? $appointment->getTimeZone() : ''
  );

$tokens = array();

$additionalTests = $this->getAdditionalTestsSelected();

foreach($additionalTests as $availableTest)
{
  $token['%AdditionalTestsSelected%'] = $availableTest->getName();
  $tokens[] = $token;
}

// here comes logic for all tokens
```

Comment: I still get the same error message. The most important thing is put the right value into array $tokens, not just get the value from $availableTest->getName()

Comment: there is a logic issue. You have several "availableTest", but only one entry in "tokens". So either you loop the full procedure inside "foreach($additionalTests as ...", or you create an array of tokens.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add each $availableTest->getName() to the array $additionalTestConfirmation you need to use `[]` on your array and the assignment operator `=`

```
foreach($additionalTests as $availableTest)
{
  $additionalTestConfirmation[] = $availableTest->getName();

}
```

You can also use the function [array_push](http://php.net/array_push)

Comment: I still get the same error message: Array to string conversion in /Users/alexhu/NetBeansProjects/menagerie/svn/trunk/apps/frontend/modules/legacy/legacy_lib/lib/classes/AppointmentTime.php on line 379